# cannot import firebase to vue after adding with NPM

Tags: firebase, vue.js

Ran

```
sudo npm i firebase
```

in the console.  In main.js I added with

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
```

and got an error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase/app' in
>   '/home/jason/Documents/Projects/bunnell-assoc/src'

in node_modules, firebase is shown as @firebase so also tried:

```
import firebase from "@firebase/app";
```

That also did not work.

Comment: Have you tried     import firebase from 'firebase'

Comment: @equi I did.  The error is slightly different but:

Comment: ./src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase' in '/home/jason/Documents/Projects/bunnell-assoc/src'

Answer (score 0):

If you installed`enter code here` firebase correctly, you shouldnt have any issues. 
First of all you need to create a new firebase file in your root. You can either put it in a folder or just leave it in the root.

In your fire base file there you can import what aspect of firebase you wanna use. If you are not oushing to production yet you can just import all of firebase like below.

**You should import do this in your firebase.js file you created in your root**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/'
```

**// set your config from your firebase app your created on the firebase website**

```
 var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAkjYLidJiyTLEPtODFfP2JVFJiXs9EZRQ",
  authDomain: "shoerack-b451e.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://shoerack-b451e.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "shoerack-b451e",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "533681909298",
  appId: "1:533681909298:web:f08c99d00568f24c99562b"
};

const fb = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export {fb}
```

***Then in your main.js you can import fb from the firebase file your created like so.***

```
import { fb } from './firebase'
```

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't post your config keys publicly